# how to iterate a list consisting of long integer value using python?

Tags: python, iteration, long-integer

I'm trying to iterate a list consisting of long integer number (more than 10 digits) but while doing it with for-loop it is taking a longer time and the shell-window get stuck during execution.

for example:
i have a list as mention below:

```
my_list: [7,31,127,2047,8191,131071,524287,838607,536870911,2147483647]
```

and i want to  iterate the above list within a function with [lucas lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) formula and  want to derive the boolean values using the lucas lehmer series where if the number has 0 in its p-2 index than the number from `my_list` should be consider as prime and return 1 (True) else 0 (False)

```
def ll_list(p):
    ll_myList = [4]
    for i in range(1,p-1):
          number = ((ll_myList[i-1])**2 -2) % (2**p - 1)
          ll_myList.append(number)
    #validating if the lucas-lehmer series (ll_myList) is a prime or not
    if ll_myList[p-2] == 0:
     return int(True)
    else:
     return int(False)
```

now when i call the `ll_list` function the shell window crashes while printing the list for each number mention in the `my_list`

```
prime_ll = [ll_list(i) for i in my_list]
print(prime_ll, '\n')
```

is there any way to speedup the iteration and at the same time i want to print the list `prime_ll`?

Comment: Your indentation in the function is incorrect.

Comment: `ll_myList` is no defined

Comment: You are aware that this algorithm tries to calculate *huge* numbers and does so many many *many* times‽ It’s not about iteration, it’s that you’re trying to crunch numbers which are too much to handle for your computer.

Comment: @deceze i know i am calculating a huge numbers so many many times. I have made certain changes to my code (please check). I just want to display the if the number mention in initial list (my_list) are prime or not using lucas-lehmer series (ll_myList). if there's any shorter way to do the above execution that please do let me know that as well.

Comment: By `ll_myList(p-2)`, did you mean `ll_myList[p-2]` by any change? Regardless, in general it is a good idea to use numpy for list and number crunching. I would look into something like `np.vectorize` to speed up computation.

Comment: @JST99 yes, sorry in hurry did a mistake.

Comment: What it means that "the shell window crashes"? Can you show some error message etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This code won't decrease the runtime of your program by much, but I think it should theoretically run faster. I basically translated the pseudo-code on the Wikipedia article you referenced.

```py
def lucas_lehmer(p):
    s = 4
    m = (1 << p) - 1
    for _ in range(p - 2):
        s = (s**2 - 2) % m
    return not s
```

The `not s` part basically checks if `s` is equal to 0. If it is, `not s` will return `True`; `False` otherwise.

The reason why it takes so long to execute this code is that there are two for loops at play: the one within the `lucas_lehmer` function, and the one that goes through each element in `my_list`. Of course, this is coupled with the fact that the numbers in your example are large by orders of magnitude.

I also found a [link](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Lucas-Lehmer_test#Python) containing other efficient implementations of this algorithm that might be of interest to you.